# Ошибка при попытке открыть браузер IE c помощью Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#ссылка на вход и драйвер
browser = webdriver.Ie("c:\\ieDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe")
link="https://www.google.com"
browser.get(link)
# ожидание чтобы визуально оценить результаты прохождения скрипта
time.sleep(10)
# закрываем браузер после всех манипуляций
browser.quit()
```

В 5 строчке (строчке с браузером) скрипт падает со следующей ошибкой:

> ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
>   Трассировка стека:
>    File "C:\Users\belkina\source\repos\try_IE\try_IE\try_IE.py", line 5, in 
>      browser = webdriver.Ie("c:\ieDriver\IEDriverServer.exe")
>   Модуль "**main**" загружен
>   Модуль "runpy" загружен
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
>       httplib_response = self._make_request(
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
>       six.raise_from(e, None)
>     File "", line 3, in raise_from
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
>       httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
>       response.begin()
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 303, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 264, in _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
>     File "C:\Users\belkina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>   ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

IE драйвер в папке лежит, также он есть в переменной PATH. Однако если не писать путь до файла, то возникает такая же ошибка.

Работает для Google Chrome и Opera. Также не работает для Edge.

Как исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите тут про настройки: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: @gil9red не помогло :с